# NativeScript buttons not resizing on device orientation change with FlexboxLayout

Tags: flexbox, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm currently using the FlexboxLayout in NativeScript 3.1 to layout a collection of equally-sized buttons.

The layout works correctly when the application first loads, regardless of the device orientation (see portrait screenshot).

However, when the device is rotated, the buttons' backgrounds and borders do not resize as expected (see landscape screenshot). The buttons' text frame does expand, as does the clickable area of the button.

This issue only occurs with iOS. The view resizes correctly when running the application on Android devices.

```
<Page>
    <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
        <Button class="btn btn-outline" flexGrow="1" text="1"></Button>
        <Button class="btn btn-outline" flexGrow="1" text="2"></Button>
        <Button class="btn btn-outline" flexGrow="1" text="3"></Button>
        <Button class="btn btn-outline" flexGrow="1" text="4"></Button>
        <Button class="btn btn-outline" flexGrow="1" text="5"></Button>
    </FlexboxLayout>
</Page>
```

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]